# Gravitee.io websocket connection

Tags: websocket, port, spring-websocket, gravitee

I set up an API Gateway through Gravitee.io and a Springboot application, and everything seems to work fine as per the rest endpoints, running in https also.

Now, I would like to open a websocket connection through the same port (8080), but when the client tries to do it, this error come up server-side:

**Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null**

Looking for some solutions online, seems like a port issue, which could be potentially easy to manage with a tomcat server. But there is a way to address this issue using Gravitee.io ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to create an issue in gravitee.io repository at https://github.com/gravitee-io/issues/issues/new

Websocket is not yet ready within Gravitee.io

Comment: issue tracking the websocket on gravitee progress: https://github.com/gravitee-io/issues/issues/1899

Comment: Websocket support has been provided as part of the 1.26.0 version of Gravitee.io. See changelog: https://github.com/gravitee-io/issues/blob/master/CHANGELOG.adoc#apim---1260-2019-05-21